# Test scenarios for tip webhook test

Tags: foursquare

I am developing a new feature, which will listen to tip notifications on venues, and I am having trouble to test it.
As far as I could check, to create a venue, and subscribe it on my foursquare app, I need to pay.

Is there any alternative to simulate or test, tip notifications?
On the app there is a test button, that only send checkin notifications.
I need to test it on dev environment before sending an untested code to production.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get venue notifications for venues that you are a manager of.

See info on the venue push API here. https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/realtime

> This API is designed for applications whose users are managers of
>   venues, allowing the application to get a real-time view of activity
>   at their venues. The Venue Push API will push to your application
>   content from venues managed by any of your application's authorized
>   users (or at a home venue that was created by one of your
>   application's authorized users). Supported venue content are
>   check-ins, likes, tips, and photos at the venue.
>
> It's important to stress that in order for your app to see pushes for
>   a venue, at least one of this venue's managers must have authorized
>   use of your app, otherwise you may see “Your app can't see pushes from
>   that venue” errors.

Comment: So as a developer, if I want to test my app before going to production, I have to create a fake venue, pay $20, and then, start testing it.
Support answered me I can add a place myself, but this is not returned as my venue by api, so it didn't work.
That's exactly what I didn't want to do.

Comment: This API should only be used by managers of real venues. If you own a venue why would you need to create a fake one to test?

Comment: In case it's not clear.
I work on a software company, I am developing an app to my customer. The customers of my customer are venue managers. My customer estimates that about 10.000 venues will be using this app, and, I need to test venues ratings using real time API.
As I am just a developer, I am not a venue manager, and I need to use real time API. Hope this clarify my situation.

Answer (score 0):

After exchanging several emails with api@foursquare.com, they set me as a manager of a venue I created on http://foursquare.com/add-place, and finally I could move on with my tests.

I strongly recommend to Foursquare to create some kind of test for all possible Real Time API notifications, or create some kind of sandbox.

Thanks.